# Regular expression for converting rtf to text in python

Tags: python, regex, rtf

I am going to use this Regular expression on my rtf file:

```
((?:^|\s)[^\s\\]+(?:\\(?!line)[A-Za-z]+\n?(?:-?\d+)?[ ]?)+)(\b[^\s\\])
```

As you see in https://regexr.com/

**xxx\par\fi-240\li720** could not be matched completely due to having "-->" after it in my rtf file. The regular regex can only detect  "**xxx\par\fi-**"

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

This is my rtf file:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf2513
\cocoatextscaling0\cocoaplatform0{\fonttbl\f0\froman\fcharset0 Times-Roman;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
\paperw15000\paperh15840\margl1440\margt1440\margr1440\margb1440\deftab1134\widowctrl\lytexcttp\formshade\headery720\footery720\pgwsxn15000\pghsxn15840\marglsxn1440\margtsxn1440\margrsxn1440\margbsxn1440\pgbrdropt32\pard\pard\fi-240\li720\tx1200\tx1920\tx2640\tx3360\tx4080\tx4800\tx5520\tx6240\tx6960\tx7680\tx8400\tx9120\tx9840\tx10560\itap0\nowidctlpar\plain\f2\fs20\b\chshdng0\chcfpat0{XX, XX   XX\plain\f2\fs20\chshdng0\chcfpat0\par\fi-240\li720\tx1200\tx1920\tx2640\tx3360\tx4080\tx4800\tx5520\tx6240\tx6960\tx7680\tx8400\tx9120\tx9840\tx10560 URN: xxx  DOB: xx  Sex: XX\par\fi-240\li720\tx1200\tx1920\tx2640\tx3360\tx4080\tx4800\tx5520\tx6240\tx6960\tx7680\tx8400\tx9120\tx9840\tx10560 Home address: 3 xxx xx, xxxxx 3134\par\pard\fi-240\li720\pard\pard\fi-240\li720\itap0\nowidctlpar Home Phone:   Mobile Phone:}
xxxx\par\fi-240\li720 swab xxx\par\fi-240\li720 to d/w xxxx\par\fi-240\li720 -->case x/  XX\par\fi-240\li720 to x/x xxx}
```

Comment: Why isn't it enough to do `re.sub` replacing `r"\\[a-z0-9-]"` with an empty string>

Comment: Because the goal of this regular expression is to decompressing glued lines, so we should keep it, as a text is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

The current pattern captures `(\b[^\s\\])` in the last group, which starts with a word boundary and expects to match a single non whitespace char except `\`

In the example data, the next char after the whitespace char is a `-`, and there is no word boundary between a whitespace char and `-`.

What you might do is use an alternation which also accepts a `-` after it `(\b[^\s\\]|-)`

The pattern would then look like

```
((?:^|\s)[^\s\\]+(?:\\(?!line)[A-Za-z]+\n?(?:-?\d+)?[ ]?)+)(\b[^\s\\]|-)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fdqyw3/1)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that it can be anything not just -, it can be space as well. Also when I add "|" in the boundary, it is going to not detect another part: \cell\row\trowd\trleft1680\trgaph30\cellx3905\cellx6415\cellx8925\cellx10512\intbl\cell Potassium Level\cell T/F mmol/L  Normal\cell (Unauth)\cell\row\trowd\trleft1680\trgaph30\cellx3905\cellx6415\cellx8925\cellx10512\intbl\cell Chloride Level\cell T/F mmol/L  Normal\cell (Unauth)\cell\row\trowd\trleft1680\trgaph30\cellx3905\cellx6415\cellx8925\cellx10512\intbl\cell Bicarbonate.   see it here: https://regex101.com/r/nPlnLB/1

Comment: @Siamak I am not sure what you mean by that. Can you share a regex101 link with the strings that you want to match and which ones you don't want to match?

Comment: [link](https://regex101.com/r/nPlnLB/1) You can see the text here. I want to be exactly the same information be matched + the problem of `fi-240` and `fi-480`. As you can see in the link, `xxx\par\fi-240\li720` could not be matched completely due to having "-->" after it in my rtf file. The regular regex can only detect `xxx\par\fi-`. And also `\par\fi-480\li1440\tx1680\tx2400\tx3120\tx3840\tx4560\tx5280\tx6000\tx6720\tx7440\tx8160\tx8880\tx9600\tx10320\tx11040\plain\f2\fs20\b\cf1` is not matched here. When I add `(\b[^\s\\]|-)`, it just solved the first problem not  `fi-480` @the-fourth-bird

Comment: @Siamak Try it like this with a match only `(?<!\S)[^\s\\]+(?:\\(?!line)[A-Za-z][^\s\\]*)+(?= +[^\s();]|;\\)` See https://regex101.com/r/JjFidv/1 This way to can specify in the positive lookahead what is allowed at the right.

Comment: @The-fourht-bird, not really, because I need two groupings. But it was very useful, I got an idea and with a change, I solved my problem. thank you so much